# Why don't Klingon weapons have sheathes?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, klingon

Many Klingon weapons are featured during the *Star Trek* television series, and the characters display a reverence for them, much like a Japanese sword master would have for a fine piece of craftsmanship.

A good traditional Japanese sword will slice right through you if you bump into it lightly, but the Bat'leth is casually strapped to the back or hung to the wall.  In "Ethics", Worf's son Alexander is seen walking down the corridors casually flipping around the dreaded Hegh'bat ceremonial knife.

Klingons value courage, but they are not stupid.  So what gives?

Comment: [This type of Klingon knife](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/D'k_tahg) is carried in a sheath...

Comment: And if you want to bring real-life into it, stopping blades with another blade is plain stupid.  That's something Hollywood started because it looks cool.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Japanese sword sharpness is mythological anyway, and mostly involved the technique of the user.  It's said to come in part from folding the metal thousands of times, but that was only done to remove impurities - something we have far more efficient ways to do in modern times.

Comment: Because a Klingon is always ready for battle.

Comment: @Richard: Using a sheath means one is unready for battle?

Comment: @JamesSheridan - it certainly does. In a fight between a man with his sword in his hand and one with his sword in a sheath, I know where I'd put my money.

Comment: @Richard - sheath can be used to parry/block. And you can rarely move into closing range fast enough that an alert and trained person can't unsheath their blade by the time you are within striking range.

Comment: @Izkata I'm fairly certain parrying has been an integral part of swordplay pretty much always. Can you explain your comment a bit?

Comment: @Angew The idea of a parry is to deflect the blow, not to block and hold it against your blade.  That, I suspect, is what Izkata meant.

Comment: @Zibbobz I see; makes sense.

Comment: @Angew Yes, what Zibbobz said.  I think I even remember them covering it on Mythbusters, using a katana-style sword:  A direct block instead of parry could snap one in half.  And even if it didn't, all the knicks in the blade would dull it very quickly

Comment: @Izkata, Even contemporary swords in other regions had better materials. Japan is not well-known for its iron mines! http://knowyourmeme.com/photos/673619-gif

Comment: @Izkata In fact the folding of the metal is done 8-20 times and does indeed purify the steel. However it is the construction from a high carbon "edge" steel with a low carbon "core" steel which are forged together and heat treated that gives a katana its hard and sharp edge with a resilient core. A sharp edge is indeed a sharp edge, but the katana was seriously advanced metal working for 500 years ago.

Comment: As for Alexander casually flipping the knife around, he wasn't a very proficient fighter or Klingon and likely found the blade to be a more "cool" toy, a la teens with a flip blade, than as a respected weapon.

Comment: @Richard: In addition to what DVK said, sheaths also protect bladed weapons from damage, as well as the sort of moisture build-up that can make gripping them difficult in a pinch. The latter is also partly why many warriors have worn gloves or taped their hands before combat, incidentally.

Comment: Sheath? Only a weakling P'TACH would need a sheath for his blade. <spits on the ground>

Comment: I think that if Klingons hurt themselves wielding a Bat'leth, they attitude would be that they deserved the injury for their incompetence.

Answer (score 9):

From the Memory Alpha page on [Bat'leth](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Bat%27leth):

> Having always been irritated that films seemed to keep portraying weapons that were meant to look appealing but actually couldn't be handled practically, Dan Curry had been envisioning a pragmatic style of weapon for a long time, thinking of it as basically a **staff weapon infused with Oriental influence**. ([Star Trek: The Next Generation 365, p. 178](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_365); [Star Trek: The Next Generation - The Continuing Mission, p. 179](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_-_The_Continuing_Mission))

...

> I was also thinking about the **Chinese double ax**, **Chinese fighting crescents**, and the Tai Chi sword. I combined elements of all those things in order to come up with an ergonomically sound weapon." ([Star Trek: The Next Generation 365, p. 178](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_365))

(Emphasis Mine)

The Bat'leth draws numerous reference points from weapons that go unsheathed - so it would make sense that the Bat'leth as well would go unsheathed.

Or from a more pragmatic standpoint...well just look at the thing!

[image]

It's got four curved points and three hand grips.  How would you even design a sheath for a weapon like that?  Not to mention the badass resilience of Klingons likely makes self-injury a less worrying prospect.

Comment: I can certainly envision an effective cover for use in peace-tying a bat'leth, but coming up with a sheath from which you could quickly draw the weapon is difficult.

Comment: "How would you even design a sheath for a weapon like that" A rectangular fold of leather.

Comment: @cmc Either the Bat'leth would pierce the leather, or it would dull the blades considerably, or both.  Neither is desireable for a Klingon weapon.

Comment: "Having always been irritated that films seemed to keep portraying weapons that were meant to look appealing but actually couldn't be handled practically, Dan Curry" decided to design a weapon that makes many real-world martial-artists, myself included, laugh at the idea that it could ever be useful in combat. The bat'leth may actually be worse than just fighting with your hands and feet. It certainly has nothing on a sword, even a two-handed one, or the very bladed weapons Curry mentions. And that only counting bladed weapons, ignoring arguably more effective clubbing weapons.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Klingons valuing courage, they also value honor, bravery and skill with weapons. They are not ones to coddle their children, they won't coddle their warriors.

A Klingon sheathing their blade would be seen as weak and afraid. Other Klingons would assume that they were foolish and/or clumsy, and if that Klingon had any honor to speak of they would face constant challenges to their ability.

And while a sheathe has a place in *human* combat, to a Klingon it would be seen as just one more thing in the way of delivering the killing blow. Take the Kill Bill trailer fight scene as an example. Although used primarily for comedic effect, Black Mamba is unable to unsheathe her sword due to the close quarters.

Comment: Your second paragraph is demonstrably false. Klingons have been shown with sheathed blades - not to mention holstered firearms - on many occasions. In fact, most Klingons seem to carry a small sheathed dagger at all times.